# XSLT stop foreach when value is found

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is it possible in an xslt mapping to do the following?

1. Go through n segments.
2. Select the first segment of /.../SOMETHING/ where (TEST_1 unequal to "VALUE_1" AND TEST_2 unequal to “VALUE_2”) and pick the FIELD value. Stop when such a segment is found.
3. If no result but there is a TEST_1 equals “VALUE_1” AND TEST_2 unequal to “VALUE_2"), then FIELD gets value "" (empty string). Stop when such a segment is found.

I now have the following XSLT:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="/.../SOMETHING/">
                    <xsl:variable name="var10_cur" select="."/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="TEST_1">
                        <xsl:variable name="var11_cur" select="."/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var10_cur/TEST_2">
                            <xsl:variable name="var12_cur" select="."/>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="(($var11_cur != 'VALUE_1') and ('VALUE_2' != .))">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$var10_cur/FIELD">
                                        <xsl:variable name="var13_cur" select="."/>
                                        <FIELD>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </FIELD>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="(('VALUE_2' != .) and ('VALUE_1' = $var11_cur))">
                                    <FIELD>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                                    </FIELD>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

However, this goes through all the n segments and applies part of the logic but doesn't pick only the first segment. It will continue looping through all the n segments despite already finding a result for step 1.

Is it possible to alter this XSLT in such a way that it does exactly what the algorithm says? Can i add a BREAK statement somewhere in the XSLT?

Comment: No, it is **not** possible to exit `xsl:for-each` because **`xsl:for-each` is not a "loop"**. However, it is very simple to pick the first node that satisfies some condition using an expression like `some/node[condition=true()][1]`. Ask about your *real* problem and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be making this far too difficult: no need for `xsl:for-each` here. This should be about 2 lines of code, not the 25 you have shown.

> Select the first segment of /.../SOMETHING/ where (TEST_1 unequal to
> "VALUE_1" AND TEST_2 unequal to “VALUE_2”) and pick the FIELD value.
> Stop when such a segment is found.

That's `/.../SOMETHING[not(TEST_1="VALUE_1"][not(TEST2="VALUE_2)][1]/FIELD`

The second part of the question (if no value is found...) involves combining the results of two such expressions E1 and E2. There are various ways of doing this. Since you're still on XSLT 1.0, the simplest is probably

```
<xsl:variable name="X" select="(E1)"/>
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$X">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$X"/>
   <xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="(E2)"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

(If you jump all the way forwards to XSLT 4.0, it's just `E1 otherwise E2`).